# How to achieve this colored-haze effect in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, reverse-engineering, effect

I really like the colored-haze in this photo:

http://meiirene.35photo.ru/photo_372234/

How do I do it in Lightrooom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a Lightroom effect, it's just the effect of shooting during Golden Hour (an hour or so before sunset in this case, I think), and shooting into the sun: result, warm, soft sunlight. The little bokeh dots floating around appear to be dandelion seeds in the air catching the light.

Comment: Can I emulate this in Lightroom?

Comment: Not really, there's no substitute for good light. If it was as easy as a bit of tweaking in Lightroom everyone would do it. As it is, you need to be willing to find good locations and wait for the light.

Comment: Looking at the photo again, I think it definitely involves some kind of fill light, I guess a flash light. Otherwise, the contrast would be too great and the background would be washed out. Do you think so?

Comment: Definitely possible: the background isn't blown which suggests some kind of full was used. It could well be a flash or perhaps a reflector.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the light source while was behind the subject, the white balance seems to be shifted to the warmer side.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can't capture the true beauty of sunset light you can do a somewhat realistic effect in Lightroom. You need to scroll down on the sidebar until you reach split-toning. In there you should see sliders. You then set the highlights to a gold-ish colour (you can tweak this) change the balance to something in the region of 60-100. and the shadows to a grey-blue colour. Tweak to your liking. I also like to add a radial filter and move it to where the light source would be, invert it, and apply a slightly warm temperature and increase the exposureslightly. Thus making a somewhat nice glow around the light source.